# 'Creating a footnote or (an) endnote reference'

Tags: syntax, attachment-ambiguity

> Beware that creating **a footnote** or **an endnote reference** from a table is not yet possible.

The above sentence is from the manual I'm working on.

My question is whether it is correct to keep *an* before *endnote*, and I mean syntax rather than style. I'm concerned that *an* will probably disconnect *reference* from *footnote*. So instead of

> Beware that creating **a footnote reference** or **an endnote reference** from a table is not yet possible.

it will mean

> Beware that creating **a footnote (not a footnote reference)** or **an endnote reference** from a table is not yet possible.

Comment: "Beware" has a stronger meaning than necessary in a tech manual. "Be aware" is probably closer to your intention.

I suggest this rewording: "Be aware that ***creating a reference to a footnote or endnote*** from a table is not yet possible."

Comment: @gotube Thanks, gotube. By the way, are there any other reasons, apart from style, to not use "an" before "endnote" in this new version?

Comment: Yes. In your top example, the "an" suggests that the two items in the list are "a footnote" and "an endnote reference", while without the "an", it's more likely they two items are "a footnote reference" and "an endnote reference", though it's not clear either way.

Comment: @gotube Yes, but I talk about the reworded version, "Be aware that creating a reference to a footnote or [an] endnote from a table is not yet possible." You don't use "an" there, and I wonder whether you omitted it to avoid cluttering the sentence with too many articles or by some another reason.

Comment: In that case, it's roughly the same answer: with "an endnote", it suggests the list is: "a footnote" and "an endnote from a table". Because the context makes this reading silly, it's unlikely to cause confusion, but it will cause some readers to go back and read it again to make sure it parses properly the logical way. With just "endnote" it's suggested both by the context and the syntax that the list is: "a footnote" and "an endnote".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"A footnote or endnote reference" is fine if you want to make it clear that you are contrasting two kinds of references (that is the more likely reading).

"A footnote or **an** endnote reference" is ambiguous between two readings:

- a footnote, or an endnote reference
- a footnote reference, or an endnote reference

If you want to unambiguously give the reading where the footnote is *not* a reference, you can reverse the order: "an endnote reference or a footnote".

Comment: You could also avoid noun-noun compounds altogether: "a reference to a footnote or endnote".